# How do i know it is will be periodic

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems

[image]

(system is LTI and Casual)

1)If a periodic signal is applied to the input of this system.
Does output always have to be periodic ?
2)What conditions are required for this system to be linear?

thanks for answers

Comment: Which is the output and which the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest proof uses the convolution property of discrete LTI systems.
for Continuous time:
If you write down your periodic sigal as it's Fourier series (with omega =2pi/period) and describe the output using the convolution property you have:
[image]

We get the output as Fourier series with the same period.
now the exact same thing can be applied for discrete system (by using the discrete convolution).

> 2)What conditions are required for this system to be linear?.

difference equations are analogous to differential equations. With the initial conditions at rest (if x(t)=0 for negative t then y(t)=0 as well) The differential equation describes LTI system.
The same can be shown for the discrete time case.
With initial rest Your equation will describe LTI system.

Comment: thank u so much :)